# puppeteer: Getting HTML from NodeList?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm getting a list of 30 items from the code:

```
const boxes = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelectorAll("DIV.a-row.dealContainer.dealTile")
})

console.log(boxes);

The result

{ '0': {},
  '1': {},
  '2': {},
  ....
  '28': {},
  '29': {} }
```

I have the need to see the html of the elements.

But every property I tried of `boxes` is simply `undefined`. I tried `length`, `innerHTML`, 'innerText` and some other.

I am sure of box really containing something because puppeteer's screenshot shows the content before I start to 'browse' the content of the page

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

- Use [`page.$$eval`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) to execute the selector and return the result in one step.
- Use [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to get the attributes after querying the elements.

**Code sample for `page.$$eval`**

```js
const htmls = await page.$$eval('selector', el => el.innerHTML);
```

**Code sample for `page.evaluate`**

```js
const singleBox = boxes[0];
const html = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, singleBox);
```